# How to pipe multiple parameters with PowerShell ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, powershell-cmdlet

I have the following simple PowerShell function:

```bsh
function ValueFromPipelineTest
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string] $Param1,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string] $Param2
    )

    Process
    {
        Write-Output "Param1: $Param1"
        Write-Output "Param2: $Param2"
    }
}
```

and if I pipe values into it like so:

```
'Hello' | ValueFromPipelineTest
@{ Param1 = 'Hello'; Param2 = 'there' } | ValueFromPipelineTest
```

The 1st line works as expected, producing the output:

> Param1: Hello
>
> Param2:

However the 2nd line produces the output:

> Param1: System.Collections.Hashtable
>
> Param2:

I'm actually looking to have the 2nd line produce the output:

> Param1: Hello
>
> Param2: there

I assume this is possible, but I'm just missing something. If there's a way to do it without using a `hashtable` I'm open to that. I'm just looking for an easy way to define an object with some properties and pipe it into my function.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish what I'm after? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The second one shouldn't work at all, but ValueFromPipeline is greedy and takes up the hashtable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by passing a custom object (rather than a hashtable) to your function. Example:

```
function Test-Pipeline {
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [String] $Param1,

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [String] $Param2
  )
  process {
    "Param1: $Param1"
    "Param2: $Param2"
  }
}

$obj = [PSCustomObject] @{Param1 = "Hello";Param2 = "World"}

$obj | Test-Pipeline

# Output:
#
# Param1: Hello
# Param2: World
```

Comment: I actually just discovered this on my own and was typing up my own answer when I got notified of this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) but that isn't for pipeline.

```
$Params = @{
    'Param1' = “Hello”
    'Param2' = “There”
}
ValueFromPipelineTest @Params
```

Alternatively, try the below.

```
$Params = @{
    Param1 = “Hello”
    Param2 = “There”
}


function ValueFromPipelineTest
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [hashtable]$Param
    )

    Process
    {
        Write-Output "Param1: $($Param["Param1"])"
        Write-Output "Param2: $($Param["Param2"])"
    }
}

$Params | ValueFromPipelineTest
```